# Ubuntu 18.04; WickrMe Snap gives Segmentation Error

Tags: snap, segmentation-fault

I'm installing WickrMe on my PCs.
One is a laptop, the other is a tower. Both run the same Ubuntu 18.04 and the exact same set of programs, settings and everything else.
On the laptop I had no problem at all.
On the tower, when I install WickrMe (both from the gui and/or from command line) I successfully complete the task: no errors come out and the program correctly turns out on the interface and in the Snap folder.
The problem is that when I try to run it from GUI nothing happens and when I launch it from the terminal it gives me:
"Errore di segmentazione" (I use the italian language) that I suppose is translatable as "Segmentation error" or "Segmentation fault".
All other snap packages work like a charm. I also tried to re-download the snap package, re-install it, install it from edge and candidate channels, every time with the same outcome.
Has anybody else had this kind of problem?
Does anybody know how can I try to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The *WickrMe* client is published by *Wickr*.

Therefore, you can get packaging support at https://support.wickr.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003136873-How-to-Install-on-Linux
There is a link there to submit a support request.

It will help them if you can provide some input about the issue. They need either to replicate or get enough information from your to figure out what's going on.
See https://snapcraft.io/docs/debugging-building-snaps on how to retrieve debugging information.

Comment: Thank you. I know WickrMe's publisher, and they were the first place I looked for an answer to my problem. If I copy and paste their answer it would be almost identical to yours:
"Ubuntu is published by Canonical. Therefore, etc..."
This is one of the situations that made me hate Windows. Something's not working and the only answers you get are:
Software house: "Ask Microsoft"
Microsoft: "Ask the software house"
You'll never solve the problem, get used to it.
I used to love linux because this kind of things didn't usually happen.
People used to TRY to give you answers.

Comment: If you have a reply from Wickr on this, then post it here (edit your question and post the reply verbatim). What is needed, is to see if they have a justification that the problem is really with Ubuntu and not the packaging of the snap.

This is a segmentation fault in the application, meaning that something that is different between your desktop and laptop is causing the application to crash. The application should take care such errors, and they should ask you for debugging information on the nature of the segmentation fault.